# Asymptote could not load module (filename-1.asy)

Tags: 3d, asymptote

after seeing this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114876/166730), I tried to make my own ball and stick model of a diagram. So I made the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{document}

\begin{asy}
size(300);
import solids;


// save predefined 2D orientation vectors
pair NN=N;
pair SS=S;
pair EE=E;
pair WW=W;

triple C1 = (-3.19898,0.68575,-0.09137);
triple N1 = (-2.00788,-0.15303,-0.05472);
triple H1 = (-3.17155,1.39571,-0.92422);
triple H2 = (-3.31563,1.23754,0.84706);
triple H3 = (-4.08519,0.05549,-0.21396);
triple C2 = (-0.78815,0.67831,0.01256);
triple H4 = (-1.95362,-0.69266,-0.92177);
triple C3 = (0.47237,-0.18670,0.21998);
triple H5 = (-0.86520,1.39211,0.84227);
triple H6 = (-0.69535,1.26040,-0.91400);
triple C4 = (1.73163,0.67172,0.09304);
triple N2 = (0.51467,-1.32801,-0.73516);
triple H7 = (0.46502,-0.59296,1.23918);
triple H8 = (1.39360,-1.82407,-0.57104);
triple H9 = (-0.23067,-1.96899,-0.46111);
triple O1 = (1.80456,1.88884,0.13111);
triple O2 = (2.86188,-0.07112,0.00360);
triple H10 = (3.57354,0.59879,-0.06651);

triple[] Carbon={  
  C1,C2,C3,C4,
};
triple[] Nitrogen={
  N1,N2,
};
triple[] Oxygen={
  O1,O2,
}
triple[] Hydrgeon={
  C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9,C10,
}
void Draw(guide3 g,pen p=currentpen){
  draw(
    cylinder(
      point(g,0),cylR,arclength(g),point(g,1)-point(g,0)
    ).surface(
               new pen(int i, real j){
                 return p;
               }
             )
  );
}
real cylR=0.062;

pen connectPen=lightgray
Draw(C1--N1,connectPen)
Draw(N1--C2,connectPen)
Draw(C2--C3,connectPen)
Draw(C3--C4,connectPen)
Draw(C4--O1,connectPen)
Draw(H1--C1,connectPen)
Draw(H2--C1,connectPen)
Draw(H3--C1,connectPen)
Draw(H4--N1,connectPen)
Draw(C2--H5,connectPen)
Draw(C2--H6,connectPen)
Draw(C3--H7,connectPen)
Draw(C3--N2,connectPen)
Draw(N2--H8,connectPen)
Draw(N2--H9,connectPen)
Draw(C4--O2,connectPen)
Draw(O2--H10,connectPen)

void drawSpheres(triple[] C, real R, pen p=currentpen){
  for(int i=0;i<C.length;++i){
    draw(sphere(C[i],R).surface(
                        new pen(int i, real j){return p;}
                        )
    );
  }
}

drawSpheres(Carbon,darkgray);
drawSpheres(Nitrogen,lightblue);
drawSpheres(Oxygen,red);
drawSpheres(Hydrogen,lightgray);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately it returns the error `could not load module [filedirectory-1.asy]`. I saw this link [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Asymptote:_Help) and tried to resolve the issue by making a config.asy file, and so it looks like this:

```
import settings;
dir="C:\Program Files\Asymptote";
```

But unfortunately it still does not render and gives the same error. Is there any way to resolve this issue (other asymptote diagrams work perfectly including the one where I was inspired from)?

Also, though this should probably be put as a separate question, how do I draw a double bond using the cylinder connectors in the code above?

Something like the double bond in this image 
[image]

Comment: I think you simply misspelled `Hydrgeon`, which should be `Hydrogen` and *many* `;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only fixes the errors and does the two-colored connections but not yet the double connection. There were a few typos (`Hydrgeon` should be `Hydrogen` and the elements of that array should be `H1`, `H2` etc. and not `C1`, `C2` etc.), you missed *many* `;` and then `drawSpheres` requires 3 arguments, not two, you forgot to put the second argument (radius). I also switched to `asypictureB`, if you compile the following with `pdflatex -shell-escape`,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=crystal}
size(300);
import solids;

currentprojection=orthographic (
camera=(8,5,4),
up=(0,0,1),
target=(2,2,2),
zoom=0.5
);

// save predefined 2D orientation vectors
pair NN=N;
pair SS=S;
pair EE=E;
pair WW=W;

triple C1 = (-3.19898,0.68575,-0.09137);
triple N1 = (-2.00788,-0.15303,-0.05472);
triple H1 = (-3.17155,1.39571,-0.92422);
triple H2 = (-3.31563,1.23754,0.84706);
triple H3 = (-4.08519,0.05549,-0.21396);
triple C2 = (-0.78815,0.67831,0.01256);
triple H4 = (-1.95362,-0.69266,-0.92177);
triple C3 = (0.47237,-0.18670,0.21998);
triple H5 = (-0.86520,1.39211,0.84227);
triple H6 = (-0.69535,1.26040,-0.91400);
triple C4 = (1.73163,0.67172,0.09304);
triple N2 = (0.51467,-1.32801,-0.73516);
triple H7 = (0.46502,-0.59296,1.23918);
triple H8 = (1.39360,-1.82407,-0.57104);
triple H9 = (-0.23067,-1.96899,-0.46111);
triple O1 = (1.80456,1.88884,0.13111);
triple O2 = (2.86188,-0.07112,0.00360);
triple H10 = (3.57354,0.59879,-0.06651);

triple[] Carbon={  
  C1,C2,C3,C4
};
triple[] Nitrogen={
  N1,N2
};
triple[] Oxygen={
  O1,O2
};
triple[] Hydrogen={
  H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6,H7,H8,H9,H10
};

//%place non-atom cube corners



real cylR=0.15;

void Draw(guide3 g,pen p=currentpen){
  draw(
    cylinder(
      point(g,0),cylR,arclength(g),point(g,1)-point(g,0)
    ).surface(
               new pen(int i, real j){
                 return p;
               }
             )
  );
}
void DrawTwoColors(guide3 g,pen p=currentpen,pen q=currentpen){
  draw(
    cylinder(
      point(g,0),cylR,arclength(g)/2,point(g,1)-point(g,0)
    ).surface(
               new pen(int i, real j){
                 return p;
               }
             )
  );
  draw(
    cylinder(
      point(g,1),cylR,arclength(g)/2,point(g,0)-point(g,1)
    ).surface(
               new pen(int i, real j){
                 return q;
               }
             )
  );
}


pen connectPen=lightgray;
pen connectPenH=lightgray;
pen connectPenN=lightblue;
pen connectPenO=red;
pen connectPenC=darkgray;
//Draw(C1--N1,connectPen);
DrawTwoColors(C1--N1,connectPenC,connectPenN);
Draw(N1--C2,connectPen);
Draw(C2--C3,connectPen);
Draw(C3--C4,connectPen);
//Draw(C4--O1,connectPen);
DrawTwoColors(C4--O1,connectPenC,connectPenO);
Draw(H1--C1,connectPen);
Draw(H2--C1,connectPen);
Draw(H3--C1,connectPen);
Draw(H4--N1,connectPen);
Draw(C2--H5,connectPen);
Draw(C2--H6,connectPen);
Draw(C3--H7,connectPen);
Draw(C3--N2,connectPen);
Draw(N2--H8,connectPen);
Draw(N2--H9,connectPen);
//Draw(C4--O2,connectPen);
DrawTwoColors(C4--O2,connectPenC,connectPenO);
Draw(O2--H10,connectPen);

void drawSpheres(triple[] C, real R, pen p=currentpen){
  for(int i=0;i<C.length;++i){
    draw(sphere(C[i],R).surface(
                        new pen(int i, real j){return p;}
                        )
    );
  }
}

real radC=0.45;
real radN=0.6;
real radO=0.6;
real radH=0.3;


drawSpheres(Carbon,radC,darkgray);
drawSpheres(Nitrogen,radN,lightblue);
drawSpheres(Oxygen,radO,red);
drawSpheres(Hydrogen,radH,lightgray);

\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

you'll get

[image]

One of the big advantages of `asypictureB` is that you can use LaTeX to control some parameters in the asymptote picture.

As you see, I added three 2-colored connections, but it will be straightforward to change any connection to this style. What I did not do is the double connection, also because I do not know in which plane they ought to be.