# Densest sphere packing

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I would like to represent the densest sphere packing in dimension 3
as the following picture, for a beamer presentation.

[image: Sphere packing]

Is Tikz the way to go for it? It is not a real 3D drawing since I only want a fixed representation of the picture, right?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Welcome! Maybe [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448772/121799) is related?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By nesting 2 for-loops one could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {4,...,0}{
    \foreach \y in {\x,...,4}{    
        \draw[fill=white] (0.6*\x,-\y+0.3*\x) circle (0.55) (-0.6*\x,-\y+0.3*\x) circle (0.55);
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @KJO Please keep your answer, I very much prefer the compact syntax with the loops

Comment: @Dynamite Excellent :-) also the answer of KJO. Many sincere compliments.

Comment: Beautiful and elegant, very nicely done

Comment: Nice! (You could replace the inner loop by `\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \z using {int(mod(\x+\y,2)+mod(\y,2))}] in {\x,...,4}{    
        \draw[fill=white] 
  \ifnum\z=0
  [fill=blue!10]
  \fi 
  (0.6*\x,-\y+0.3*\x) circle (0.55) 
  (-0.6*\x,-\y+0.3*\x) circle (0.55);
    }`...)

Comment: Perfect thank you very much !

Comment: Alternative colors: `\foreach \x in {4,...,0}{
    \foreach \y in {\x,...,4}{   
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\val}{ 0.6 + 0.1*(4-\y) }
        \definecolor{MyColor}{gray}{\val}
        \draw[fill=MyColor] 
        (0.6*\x, -\y+0.3*\x) circle (0.55) %node {\x, \y}
        (-0.6*\x,-\y+0.3*\x) circle (0.55); %node {\x, \y};
    }
}`